# Create CloudFormation stack from AWS Lambda function, passing API Gateway parameters

Tags: api, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless, gateway

I am unable to get parameters in Lambda function. If I mention parameters value in lambda it works fine. when I remove parameters values from Lambda function and try from API gateway or test lambda it process default parameters values. please help
My Lambda function is :

```
import boto3
import time
import json

datetime = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
stackname = 'myec2'
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
response = client.create_stack(
  StackName= (stackname+ '-' + datetime),
  TemplateURL='https://testnaeem.s3.amazonaws.com/ec2tags.yaml',
  Parameters=[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "MyInstanceName",
    "ParameterValue": " "
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "MyInstanceType",
    "ParameterValue": " "
  }
]
)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
            return(response)
```

My CloudFormation template is:

```
---
Parameters:
  MyInstanceType:
    Description: Instance type description
    Type: String
  MyInstanceName:
    Description: Instance type description
    Type: String  

Resources:
  MyInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      ImageId:  ami-047a51fa27710816e
      InstanceType: !Ref MyInstanceType
      KeyName: miankeyp
      Tags:
        - Key : Name
          Value : !Ref MyInstanceName
        - Key : app 
          Value : demo
```

Please help what changes required in the Lambda function.

My test Values are:

```
{
  "MyInstanceName": "demott",
  "MyInstanceType": "t2.micro"
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify again, what does not work, what is expected behavior, how to reproduce the issue, what are the error messages?

Comment: No error, but take parameter values as default. as i am passing instance size t2.micr, but it is taking m1.small.

Comment: There are no default values in your template and in the lambda you are just using empty strings.

Comment: no default in template but still launching ec2 with m1.small instance.

Comment: If i use string in lambda function then it's ok and working fine. but I want to pass string "Parameters values" from API gateway or lambda test function.

Comment: Can you please specify exactly what is your API gateway setup? Why it does no work? How do you pass the instance type parameter through the api?

Comment: I am using Rest API and passing parameters in API URL as  https://****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/*/enque?MyInstanceName=test&MyInstanceType=t2.micro    ,   It launches successfully launched instance but m1.small size instead of t2.micro

Comment: mapping template in API gateway is:  { 
  "MyInstanceName": "$input.params('MyInstanceName')",
  "MyInstanceType": "$input.params('MyInstanceType')" 
}

Comment: You are not using any parameters from api in your lambda function. The function you provided is your actual code that you use?

Comment: this is what asking, does I have to mention something special in lambda function to get parameters from API. or i am missing any code line in function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code of your lambda function. Please check comments in the code for clarification:

```
import boto3
import time
import json

datetime = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
stackname = 'myec2'
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print(event) # to check what your even actually is
    # it will be printed out in CloudWatch Logs for your
    # function

    # you have to check what the event actually looks like
    # and adjust event['MyInstanceName'] and event['MyInstanceType']
    # in the following code

    response = client.create_stack(
      StackName= (stackname+ '-' + datetime),
      TemplateURL='https://testnaeem.s3.amazonaws.com/ec2tags.yaml',
      Parameters=[
      {
        "ParameterKey": "MyInstanceName",
        "ParameterValue": event['MyInstanceName']
      },
      {
        "ParameterKey": "MyInstanceType",
        "ParameterValue": event['MyInstanceType']
      }
    ]
    )

    return(response)
```

By the way, such function and API gateway can spin up a lot of ec2 instances very quickly. So that you are aware of this.

Comment: Thank you Marcin this solution is working.  yes but my manager demanding such type of API to auto deploy resources. is their any solution to secure

Comment: @Naeem Glad it works. Its use-case specific. If your manager want's this, then I guess he/she must have a good reason for that.